# Motor needed for a vibration plate machine

Tags: vibration-motor

I have seen some vibration plate excercise machines and was wondering if I could manage to design some similar machine.

some specs to begin:

- maximum load (body weight) of 140kg
- plate vibration frequency ranging from 5Hz up to 30Hz
- vibration amplitude 0..+/-5 mm
- maximum power consumption 400VA
- device shall not weight more than 30kg

Which type of motor is best suited to meet these requirements?

- stepper motor
- eccentric weight vibration motor
- piezoelectric vibration motor
- LRA motor

I would appreciate your response and thanks for your time in helping me

Comment: What is the design of mechanism you propose? As an aside, please don't rely on EEs knowing much about exercise machines LOL. 400 VA seems a little light on requirements based on your numbers. I estimate more like 700 VA.